# How can this function be simplified?

Tags: list, haskell, lambda, anonymous, haskell-prelude

This is the function:

```
f []      = []
f (h:t)   = (\x -> x - h) : f t
```

It takes a list and returns a list of anonymous functions, that substract each each element from x.

Apparently there is some way to write this whole function in 20 characters or less.

I tried to do it with `map` but that just applies a function to each element of the list. I also tried to replace the anonymous function with `(-a)` which didn't work either.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Seems like a perfect question for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, `(\x -> x - h)` can be written as `(- h)` iirc

Comment: Shouldn't the correct function be: `f (h:t)   = (\x -> x - h) : f t`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That's a bit of a strange corner of the Haskell syntax. `(- h)` means to negate the number `h`. `subtract h` would be equivalent to that lambda.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem yes you're right, fixed it

Comment: @Carcigenicate Unfortunately, no: `(-h)` is unary minus, and not a section! That's why we have `subtract h` from the `Prelude`.

Comment: @chi Ah, damn. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use:

```
f :: Num a => [a] -> [a -> a]
f = map subtract
```

Since [`subtract :: Num n => n -> n -> n`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:subtract), it thus means that we map every element `h` from the list to a function `subtract h`. Subtract `h` subtracts `h` from any given value `x`. So `subtract h x == x - h`.